# Show that a random sum of normal random variables is normal

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We know that if $X_1 \sim \hbox{Normal}(\mu_1, \sigma^2_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \hbox{Normal}(\mu_2, \sigma^2_2)$, then:
$$X = X_1+X_2 \sim \hbox{Normal}\left(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2\right)$$

But how about a random sum?  That is, consider $X_j \overset{iid}{\sim} \hbox{Normal}(0,\sigma^2)$  and $N \sim \hbox{Poisson} (\lambda)$ independent of $(X_j)_{j=1}^{\infty}$. So, define
$$X = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_N$$
What is the distribution of $X$?

It is straightforward to show that $E[X]=0$ and $\mathbf{var}(X)= \lambda \mathbf{var}(X_j)=\lambda \sigma^2$. So I think that $X \sim \hbox{Normal}(0,\lambda \sigma^2)$. But I can't show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false. $X$ has a [compound Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution) with characteristic function
$$E[e^{i\xi(X_1+...+X_N)}]=e^{\lambda(e^{-\xi^2\sigma^2/2}-1)}$$
which is not a normal characteristic function.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. If we had $(X_j)$ just independently but not identically distributed. For example, suppose $X_1$, $X_2$, ... with different normal distributions. What would we have?

Comment: @AndréGoulart I don't think I am aware of research material on such objects (and if there are nice examples at all), so I can't point you to a reference. Would be worth a new question!